# ORACLE: How to get earliest record of certain value when value alternates?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'll simplify what I'm looking for here.

I have a table that stores an asset name, the date (job runs daily), and a value that is either 1 or 0 that indicates whether the asset is out of compliance. 
I need to get the earliest date where the value is 0.

The issue I run into is that the issue can be intermittent, such that the same asset may show as in compliance, then out, and then in again. I want to retrieve the earliest date it was out of compliance *this time*.

```
Asset    Date       Compliant
NAME     2-FEB-18   0
NAME     1-FEB-18   0
NAME     31-JAN-18  1
NAME     30-JAN-18  0
```

In this example, I want to retrieve 1-FEB-18, and not 30-JAN-18.

I'm using a subquery into a temp table that retrieves the MIN(date) which would return 30-JAN-18. Thoughts?

Anonymized current subquery:

```
least_recent_created AS
(
SELECT t.date,t.ASSET, t.DATABASE_NAME FROM table t
WHERE t.date = 
(
SELECT MIN(date)
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t.ASSET_ID = t2.ASSET_ID
AND t.DATABASE_NAME = t2.DATABASE_NAME
AND t2.compliant = 0
)
)
```

Comment: What should happen if there is no such date? (Like in your example if the latest record also had "1" in the "compliant" column)

Comment: Post your existing query and explain your exact problem.

Comment: Mat, if the asset has never been out of compliance, the subquery will not pick it up, as it's filtered to "Compliant = 0"

Comment: PM 77-1: I updated with the subquery. The exact problem is that I'm trying to capture the earliest time in a string of non-compliance without capturing the date that the asset was non-compliant if it has been compliant since.

If on day 1 it was non-compliant, day 2 compliant, days 3 and 4 non-compliant it should return the date for day 3, not day 1.

Answer (score 0):

You want the earliest out-of-compliance date since the last in compliance.  If the asset was never in compliance, I assume you want the earliest date.

```
select t.asset, min(date)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when t.complaint = 1 then date end) over (partition by asset) as max_compliant1_date
      from t
     ) t
where complaint = 0 and
      (date > max_complaint1_date or max_complaint1_date is null)
group by t.asset;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT "Asset", MAX("Date")
FROM (
   SELECT "Asset", "Date", "Compliant",       
          CASE 
             WHEN "Compliant" = 0 AND 
                  LAG("Compliant") OVER (PARTITION BY "Asset" 
                                         ORDER BY "Date") = 1 THEN "Date"
          END AS OutOfComplianceDate    
   FROM mytable)  t
WHERE OutOfComplianceDate IS NOT NULL   
GROUP BY "Asset"
```

The inner query identifies 'Out-of-Compliance' dates, that is dates where the current record has `"Compliant" = 0` whereas the immediately preceding record has `"Compliant" = 1`.

The outer query returns the latest 'Out-of-Compliance' date per `"Asset"`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/615ee3/10)